# Pass data from one page to anothe file/page in wordpress

Tags: pages, forms, fatal-error

I have my custome theme in wordpress.This is the path of my custome theme.
**C:\wamp\www\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\sscy1002\sscy1002**

I have created a Page in wordpress which contains some form elements. Here is my Page Code :

```
 <form action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Query.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="contact">
<label for="author">Name:</label> <input class="required input_field" id="author" type="text" name="author" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
    <label for="email">Email:</label> <input class="validate-email required input_field" id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input class="input_field" id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
    <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea class="required" id="text" cols="0" name="text" rows="0"></textarea>
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>
    <label for="image">Image:</label><input type="file" name="file" />

    <input class="submit_btn float_l" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    <input class="submit_btn float_r" id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />

    </form>
```

And here is my Query.php code under **C:\wamp\www\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\sscy1002\sscy1002** directory :

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<?
$name=$_POST['author'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$message=$_POST['text'];
$image=$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"imagess/".$image);
echo $name."<br/>";
echo $email."<br/>";
echo $subject."<br/>";
echo $message."<br/>";
echo "<img src='imagess/".$image."' alt='image'>";
?>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

But when I am submitting form I am getting fatal error :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\sscy1002\sscy1002\Query.php on line 2**

Please help me how to pass transfer data from one page to another file(or if Page) in wordpress. I also searched answer on google but and tried all the way which I got from google but not working.

Sorry about wrong formatting of Question. Please help me!!!!
Thanks!!!

Comment: Create Query.php as page template and add it to page then pass url of this page in form action attribute.http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Comment: There's no need to create a non-standard WP template file for this. Why not just place your form functionality into `functions.php` where it should be? http://tommcfarlin.com/sending-data-post/

Comment: Have a look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/implementing-a-custom-form-in-wordpress/201942#201942 You would need to save data that u need in session or cookie and then on the second page u could use them...

Comment: But if u don't understend what is the problem: Problem is in that u'r loading custom php file wich is not connected to wordpress php files, so you don't have `get_header`, `add_action` atc. functions avilable. If u want to make a page witch will take your post data you should consider creating page template and submiting form to a page link wich has page template...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use functions.php to handle the form submission and send the data via AJAX.

Add a hidden field in your form with the action to be taken (on functions.php):

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_contact"/>
```

In you footer.php add the jQuery code to handle the AJAX request:

```
jQuery('#your-form').submit(ajaxSubmit);
function ajaxSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var formData = jQuery(this).serialize()

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){
       //SHOW CONFIRMATION
    },
    error: function(error){
       //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Finally, In you functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_save_contact', 'save_contact');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_contact', 'save_contact');
function save_contact(){
     //Do whatever you want here...
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

add following code before get_header()

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

you getting error because your file is not for a page created with wordpress its just a php file, you need to include load.php file to load all the required functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://example.com/page-slug/

where page-slug is page created by make Query.php as template.

```
<form action="http://example.com/page-slug/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="contact">
```

Answer (score -3):

Please replace form action path from `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` to `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

Then check it..

Comment: Please explain, how that would prevent the `Call to undefined function` error, the OP is getting.